# apt-get hangs forever during any operation involving apache2

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, apache2

I was trying to update my server (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) this morning using:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get upgrade
```

The update went smoothly, but the upgrade hangs forever at:

```
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) ...
```

So after some fruitless googling, I decide to interrupt the  install (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, kill %1) .  My next thought is to try again...

```
# apt-get upgrade
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

OK.  Let's do that:

```
# dpkg --configure -a
.... other packages being set up
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) ...
```

Again Hangs forever.  OK Let's remove apache, and start over:

```
# dpkg -P apache2
(Reading database ... 142633 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) ...
```

and we are hung again forever...  So I try the following:

```
# dpkg --purge --force-remove-reinstreq apache2
(Reading database ... 142633 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6) ...
```

and again, hangs....

Can anyone please point me to the exit of this maze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I went through and killed many processes that could have caused this, I was still hanging.   So I tried a reboot.  After rebooting, I was able to remove and reinstall apache2.