# Ubuntu 14, services don't stop, shutdown doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, apache2, tomcat7

I host a few things on my Ubuntu server.  I use Apache (80), Tomcat (8080), and PlexMediaServer (32400).

Lately I've tried to install Deluge which opened Pandora's box for me.  It hung when it got to the point "configuring apache2(versionxx)".  I had to kill the install.  This led to me noticing that no service call to apache2 or tomcat will work.

`sudo service tomcat7 (start/stop/restart)` - hangs

`sudo service apache2 (start/stop/restart)` - hangs

Getting status works, it will tell me those services are running.  I can access my pages hosted by those respective services just fine, but I can't configure the service in any way.  When I issue start/stop/restart, the system hangs on the next line until I issue CTRL + C.  Sometimes that doesn't respond and I have to use CTRL + Z.

example:

```
x@X:~$ sudo service apache2 stop

<- cursor hangs here on the next line
```

I've tried about every iteration of apt-get you can imagine, including purge, remove, install.

I've tried killall on the respective processes and another fruitless series of attempts to run apt-get, even dpkg reconfigure.  They always hang on `configuring Apache2(version)`, sometimes `removing Apache2(version)`.

I've tried strace with the PID of Apache2 (not child Apache listeners) to no avail, but really I don't know what I'm looking at.

Nothing I do will make these services respond.  What's more, I can only reboot my computer by issuing "sudo reboot --force".  Shutdown now with or without -h doesn't work, nor does sudo reboot by itself.  The computer will remain responsive and accept commands after running anything that's supposed to shut it down EXCEPT sudo reboot --force.

[This guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678455/apt-get-hangs-forever-during-any-operation-involving-apache2) was having the same issue as me, but he said a reboot allowed him to remove and reinstall apache.  That didn't work for me.

What can I do next?

Comment: Try `sudo pkill apache2`.

Comment: No luck.  After running sudo pkill apache2 and then running sudo apt-get purge apache2, it hung on:

apache2_invoke prerm: Disable module php5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much Googling, I forced a reinstall of dpkg and ran a series of cleans, autoremoves, and the like.  I also ran an apt-get update && upgrade -y which had new linux headers and a new plexmediaserver (which I had to force install).

All of a sudden I can stop/start/restart both apache2 and tomcat7, and am able to reboot by simply running sudo reboot.

I'm not 100% sure what I did if I'm honest, but I think it was largely the dpkg reinstall and the successive operations ran with the reinstalled version mentioned above.

EDIT: I will try to remember to accept my own answer.  Mods, feel free to do so before 21 hours in case I forget.  Thanks.